# Embed cloudcraft diagram into README.md on Gitlab

Tags: html, gitlab, markdown

I have a diagram on cloudcraft.co (free plan). I want this diagram to be rendered on my Gitlab README or Wiki page without saving it as a blob in my repo.

Cloudcraft has some options to export image, 2 of them are "Image export" and "Get sharable link".

- **Image export** allows to save PNG, SVG, or PDF file but with `blob:https://app.cloudcraft.co/74badb9d-...-8053bba5b60f` url. I'm not shure I can use this method.
- **Get sharable link** allows me to check "Embed into Confluence, dashboard or wiki" swith and take a url like "https://app.cloudcraft.co/view/d1702ac9-327d-44a4-88b9-e5de6b63ffb6?key=6THR1l6-a1ADiPPqHg1LeQ&embed=true" (you can open this with your browser and see SVG built in HTML).
  I tried to embed this in my `README.md` like inline HTML:

```html
    <iframe
      src="https://app.cloudcraft.co/view/d1702ac9-327d-44a4-88b9-e5de6b63ffb6?key=6THR1l6-a1ADiPPqHg1LeQ&embed=true"
      style="width:100%; height:300px;"
    ></iframe>
```

but with no luck.

What is the right way to "embed into Confluence, dashboard or wiki"?

Answer (score 0):

From email conversation with James Pond

> The best way to embed a diagram on a GitLab or GitHub project is to
> export it as an image, upload the image to your repository, and then
> include the image with Markdown, since neither of these platforms
> allow you to include an iFrame for security reasons.
>
> After exporting the diagram as an image in Cloudcraft, simply save it
> in your git repository — most people create a directory called
> `assets` to keep these images in —, and then link to it using Markdown
> syntax. For example, if you had an `assets` directory at the root of
> your repository and the diagram file was called
> `cloudcraft-diagram.png`, you would include it like this:
>
> ```
> ![Cloudcraft Diagram](assets/cloudcraft-diagram.png "Cloudcraft Diagram")
> ```
>
> ...
>
> James Pond
>
> Customer Support Engineer